# How to describe columns to be selected from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

authors table:

```
id_author
author(author name in this column)
```

author_ind table:

```
id_book
id_author
```

My query is:

```
      SELECT author
        FROM authors
   LEFT JOIN author_ind 
          ON author_ind.id_book = author_ind.id_author
   LEFT JOIN authors author 
          ON author_ind.id_author = authors.id_author
       WHERE author_ind.id_book=%d
```

I need to get the authors info from the authors table based on the id_book from the author_ind table. MYSQL error #1052 - Column 'author' in field list is ambiguous.

Little help please:)

Update: thank you everyone. correct query:

```
SELECT authors.author
  FROM authors, author_ind
 WHERE author_ind.id_book =14
   AND authors.id_author = author_ind.id_author
```

14 is just a book id, I used it to test if it worked instead of %d

Comment: `SELECT authors.author`...specify the table name before the column to eliminate ambiguity.Also fix your on conditions its like `tableA.column=tableB.someothercolumn`

Comment: query is very wrong --- and ON author_ind.id_book = author_ind.id_author

Comment: @Mihai, this way it works but return 0 rows

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan, omg...I think I got you point:)))

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're trying to get, you've made this more complex than it needs to be.  You don't need to do a 2nd join on the authors table. Also, if you only want authors who have a record in the author_ind table, you can do a `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT author
FROM authors
INNER JOIN author_ind 
      ON authors.id_author = author_ind.id_author
WHERE author_ind.id_book=%d
```